# Foreach key value

Tags: php, sql

My code is 2 parts, I can't make it one...and for many of reasons, I only can edit the first part

The first part is :

```
<?php

$w = $db->query("SELECT name,code FROM languages");
$languages = array();
while ($row = $db->fetchAll($w)) {
    $languages[] = $row['name'];
}
?>
```

The second part is :

```
<?php

foreach ($languages as $code => $name) {
    echo 'Language is : ' . $name . ' | Code is : ' . $code;
}
?>
```

And the current output is :

```
Language is : English | Code is : 0
Language is : x       | Code is : 1
ect...
```

As you can see $name is the language name and $code is a key and the key value is 0,1,2,3,..ect

What i'm trying to do is let the key ($code) = the real language code to get the output like

```
Language is : English | Code is : en
```

Any idea please ?

Thank you.

Comment: what values are stored in your database below the "code" column? (english,0),(xxx,1) etc.. or (english, en), (xxxx,yy)?

Comment: Can you redesign or modify the language table? I think, there is much more clear solution of your problem, but it requires clean model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the line

```
$languages[] = $row['name'];
```

to this one:

```
$languages[$row['code']] = $row['name'];
```

Using an array without an index (e.g. `$array[] =`) will just append your value to the end using a numerical key.

Answer (score 1):

Is the real language code stored in your database?

If so part one should be

```
 $w = $db->query("SELECT name,code FROM languages");
 $languages = array();
 while($row = $db->fetchAll($w))
{
$languages[$row['code']] = $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$languages[] = $row['name'];
```

to

```
$languages[strtolower(substr($row['name'],0,2))] = $row['name'];
```

Comment: Works great for spanish or dutch or portuguese, NOT